# Cookies not sent to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to have expressjs (4.13.4) send cookies to my clients:

```
const app = express()
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('name', 'value')
  res.end()
})
app.listen(config.port, () => console.log(`Server started at port ${config.port}`))
```

However, when I call this route I get no cookies at all..[image]

I am confused why?

Comment: Why are you passing an array as the second value to `set`? The [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set) don't seem to say that is an option.

Comment: Why are you using `set` when there is a dedicated [`cookie` method](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)?

Comment: @Quentin you are totally right, add answer and get my +1vote

Comment: @Quentin: I've tried using `cookie` as well same result...

Comment: If downvoting please at least provide a reason so that the question can be improved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use plugin to your browser to make sure that the server has sent the set-cookie header
good plugin for chrom is

[Live HTTP Header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo)

if the problem due to the browser in any way i recommend you to use curl for HTTP level testing

if you still face the problem. I recommend your to create very small project then use npm to install proper modules then just implement the critical part of your problem.

if this didn't work just take break and relax then try to solve the problem.
I think the problem would be from environment or syntactical maybe.
on any way that's the help i can give you sorry.